# how to create json from associate array

Tags: php, json, associative-array

I am new to `PHP`. So bear with me. I have to fetch songs from db. I don't know how to **initialize associate array in a for loop** using `keyValuePair.` and also add status attribute to it.

What i want is

```
{
       "status" : "true" ,// It tells whether day available or not
       "data": [
          {
             "name": "Joe Bloggs",
             "id": "203403465"
          },
          {
             "name": "Fred Bloggs",
             "id": "254706567"
          },
          {
             "name": "Barny Rubble",
             "id": "453363843"
          },
          {
             "name": "Homer Simpson",
             "id": "263508546"
          }
       ]
    }
```

**My Code**

```
$html = file_get_html('http://1stfold.com/taskbox/Farrukh/Zare/');

$output = array();// how to initialze it in for loop with keyValue pair

// Find all "A" tags and print their HREFs
foreach($html->find('.branded-page-v2-body a') as $e) 
{
    if (0 === strpos($e->href, '/watch?v')) 
    {
        $output[] = $e->href . '<br>';

        echo $e->href . '<br>';
    }   
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Within the loop just use `$output[$key] = $value;`. Is that not what you mean?

Comment: No it returns me    {
/watch?v=7Roa3aKnFoE: "/watch?v=7Roa3aKnFoE",
/watch?v=L3fbL4j48Ew: "/watch?v=L3fbL4j48Ew"
}

Comment: Yes, because there's nothing in your code that gets a name or ID from anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an array to the $output array, by simply changing this :

```
$output[] = $e->href . '<br>';
```

To this :

```
$output['data'][] = array('name' => $name_value, 'id' => $id_value);
```

This will push arrays to the the $output['data'] array.

You should add the "status" keyValuePair before the loop

Comment: Plus 1 for help and after the forloop I add 
$output['status'] = "true";